# GraphQL and N+1 problem solutions with prisma

Tags: graphql, nexus, prisma

I have a GraphQL api implemented with Nexus-graphql and Prisma + Postgres.

Prisma has a nice solution for N+1 issue with query batching when it comes to GraphQL but seems to be working on 2 levels of nesting, e.g. User -> Posts, but when we need multiple levels of GraphQL nesting (User -> Posts -> Comments -> Likes -> Users) it seems to execute hundreds of queries.

What are the general best practices for doing query optimization in such cases?
I have 2 ideas but maybe there are more:

1. Using prisma's "include" option. Construct a map of prisma relations based on the received graphql query (from "info" field) and query all the relations at once in a single query.
2. Using a dataloader, query all necessary data and save to dataloader and within the resolvers load models from dataloder.

Comment: Have you gone through the [query optimization](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/query-optimization-performance) guide in the Prisma documentation?